# C++ code for URL-encoding but cannot use curl

Tags: c++, byte, libcurl, urlencode

Is there a simple way to do URL encode in C++?

I am using byte string encode and it give wrong result

SDKXML=<CSPInput><serviceID>CSOTR39099</serviceID>&lt

**<CSPInput>    Instead of the correct format %3CCSPInput%3E**

Will somthing like libcurl work for C++

Sample Request wrongly encoded:

```
GET /sdk/servlet/abc.servlet.SampleCredit?SDKXML=&lt;CSPInput&gt;&lt;serviceID&gt;CSOTR39099&lt;/serviceID&gt;&lt
```

**<CSPInput>    Instead of the correct format %3CCSPInput%3E**

Could you please help and suggest where is the issue and propose the code to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

you can look at [houdini](https://github.com/tanoku/houdini)

&lt seems to be html encode, not url encoding